# Can matrix $B$ be factorized as $B_{n \times n} = A_{n \times m} A_{n \times m}^{T}$ in general case?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-transformations

In practice I can formulate this task as optimization and step by step modifying $A$ using gradient descent make $AA^{T}$ as close to $B$ as possible. But what does say theory about this possibility? I heard only about SVD and some other factorization methods but all of them use 2 matrix.

Comment: Don't you at least assume that $B$ is symmetric and has nonnegartive eigenvalues or something like that? I understand the title but less the body of your question.

Comment: $AA^T$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. If $B$ isn't, you're out of luck.

Comment: @PeterFranek nope. So it seems that the answer is no...
But in my case it doesn't seems to be a problem because I use symmetric one with positive elements.

Comment: It's called Cholesky decomposition